# DPM Disk Allocation

Tags: diskmanagement, scdpm

Very new to DPM and have a query regarding 'disk allocation'.  When on the 'Management' screen the 'Disk' portion shows that the 'Unallocated space' is 2.5Tb and is showing a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark.
When I do a report on 'Disk utilisation' it says that the total size is 64Tb, Allocated is 61Tb and that Used is 40Tb.
So why is it giving me a warning when the space left is about 24Tb??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between allocated and used space.
When you create a protection group, a certain amount of space is allocated to it, which DPM will try and utilise for backups for that specific group.

What you're seeing is that DPM is warning you that it thinks it doesn't have enough space unallocated.
So it might not have enough space to allocate disk space to a new protection group.

However it DOES have enough free space within the allocated space to safely back up your current protection groups.